# Prevent Abstract from using a full page

Tags: page-breaking, titles, abstract

I am trying to prevent the abstract from taking up a full page while also using `[titlepage]`. LaTeX seems to ignore any non-breaking newlines or other formatting directives and places the abstract on a new page regardless.

Using `[notitlepage]` is unfortunately not an option as I understand, as that leaves the title in its usual size, alignment and formatting and does not give me the beautiful `[titlepage]` full size title page.

here is a short example to show what I mean:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Test}
\author{me}

\maketitle

% pagebreak produced here

\begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

% unwanted pagebreak produced here

\section{section}
        \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since suppressing the `titlepage` class option is not desired, one can redefine `abstract`:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
      %\titlepage
      %\null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par%\vfil\null\endtitlepage
     }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Test}
\author{me}

\maketitle

% pagebreak produced here

\begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

% unwanted pagebreak produced here

\section{section}
        \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

When the `titlepage` option is in action, the abstract is not typeset in a `quotation` environment using `\small` font; if you want this, the redefinition is:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
      %\titlepage
      %\null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \small
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}\quotation}%
     {\quotation\par%\vfil\null\endtitlepage
     }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Test}
\author{me}

\maketitle

% pagebreak produced here

\begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

% unwanted pagebreak produced here

\section{section}
        \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned, I want the full page title, but redefining abstract works perfectly!

Comment: Also just noticed, this changes the width of the `abstract` block, which is normally slightly less wide than normal text. It should be a small fix with some `\newgeometry` but I think it should be included in case anyone else wants to do this in the future

Comment: @Atsch That's the standard behaviour with `titlepage` option. If you want the behaviour to be the same as without `titlepage` the redefinition has to be slightly modified. I added it in my updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I guess the end part of your second redefinition of `abstract` is supposed to contain `\endquotation` instead of `\quotation`.